# How Could I Convert Text to Entity Frameworks Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to store user queries in a database. The queries will then run against an entity frameworks structure. So an example would be :

```
using(AdventureWorksDB aw = new 
AdventureWorksDB(Settings.Default.AdventureWorks)) {
var newSalesPeople = from p in aw.SalesPeople
                     where p.HireDate > hireDate
                     orderby p.HireDate, p.FirstName
                     select new { Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                                  HireDate = p.HireDate };

foreach(SalesPerson p in newSalesPeople) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName);
}
}
```

How could I convert the above, if it was stored as text, to become an entity framework query that gets run? Also is there another recommended way of storing the query eg xml

Thanks for reading

Comment: What are your user queries ? Something like search parameters ?

Comment: What is it that your are trying to do? Why would you save a LINQ query as text? And even if you do, how are your going to execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears ObjectContext.CreateQuery is the best solution. As it says it enables for queries to be added to a context at runtime - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670(v=vs.110).aspx  . Also, storing the queries as a string in a database would be perfectly adequate.